# Apparent False alarm raised by Google Webmaster Tools / Search

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

Google search has been reporting

> This site may be hacked.

from a couple of days. When I look into the Webmaster Tools **>** Security Issues, this is what it says:
[image]

Now, the url in the *Sample Urls* is actually a legitimate Url and there is no spam content being served (I tried with a couple of different user agents). This looks like a false alarm to me but is there something that I might be missing?

Any suggestions on how to go about mitigating this issue?

**[EDIT]**

Show Details:
[image]

Comment: If the url on question was put there by you and your are sure your site was not hacked then that page may be be very low quality to the point google thinks it's spam.

Comment: I suggest a Fetch as Google to double-check the page. There are viruses that are designed to infect certain CMS(s) and are condition based. These interrupt the process and return hacked results even when your CMS database and other content appears to be clean.

Comment: As well, check to see if you are on a blacklist. It may be that your domain name or IP address is listed in a blacklist. Google checks these things. http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

Comment: Thanks @JohnConde - This seems to be the only probable reason. I looked up the web for tools that evaluate this, but couldn't find many relevant tools. Is there a specific tool that readily indicates the possibility of Google assuming a page to be spammy? A spam score or something like that?

Comment: What does it say when you click 'show details'?

Comment: @Max it's more of a templated response. I have attached a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the server side source code of the page on the server and look for code that does not belong. Even though you tested a few different user agents, it is trivial to make a dynamic page show different content to various users based on any factor. A hacker could also make it only happen at certain times of day, etc.

Until you've checked the server side source code, it's dangerous to assume a false alarm.

Comment: I checked the source code, it looks intact and unmodified.

Comment: It is also very common for malware to hide inside *.htaccess* files or webserver configuration files.  [Google has a good guide for removal of malware from websites](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/163634?hl=en)